# Lightweight class-to-MySQL record mapping in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, object-object-mapping

I'm using VS 2008 and .NET 3.5 framework.

I've already played a bit with `XmlSerializer`.  I've added attributes in the business object classes like

`[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute()]`

and so forth, and it works well.  It's a relatively thin mapping interface from the object structure to the XML structure.

Is there a similar procedure for doing this with objects to MySQL tables and records -- that is, something short of defining two separate frameworks for each business object?  We're already using the MySQL ADO.NET driver: http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/.  I'm trying to decide now whether I want to make the jump to something like NHibernate, or try to work with the more domain-specific MySQL driver.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking but it sounds like you asking about ORM's. Take a look at PetaPoco/Simple Data/Dapper or Massive. PetaPoco gets the thumbs up from me. They create POCO's or dynamic objects that relate to your tables and then return IEnumerable<YourTable> in query results

Comment: Jon: Yes, ORMs are closer to what I'm looking for.  I don't really have *that* many classes but every little bit helps I suppose. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If plain ADO.NET is not good enough for your requirements, you may checkout [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)* before jumping into more heavy artillery like NHibernate an EF.

*<sup>requires .NET 4.0</sup>

There are also other lightweight ORMs such as [Massive](http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive) and [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) that are also worth checking out.

Comment: Interesting link.  Thank you Darin!